# c# datagridview does not refresh after passing parameters

Tags: c#, datagridview, refresh

I am passing parameters from Form 1:Products into Form2:ProductEdit. After edit the parameters in ProductEdit, datagridview in Products does not refresh.

```
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            ProductEdit pe = new ProductEdit(dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            pe.Show(dataGridView);
        }
    }    

public ProductEdit(string PId, string PName, string PPrice)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtPId.Text = PId;
        txtPName.Text = PName;
        txtPPrice.Text = PPrice;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches to fixing this.

1. Instead of passing in strings, pass in the cells. Bind the textboxes to the cells. Then the edits made will show up in the original form as you are directly modifiying it.
2. When product edit is closing, write the values in the textboxes back to `dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells(xxxx)`

---

An example of approach 1: ( untested)

```
ProductEdit pe = new ProductEdit(dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1], dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2], dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3]);

public ProductEdit(DataGridViewCell PId, DataGridViewCell PName, DataGridViewCell PPrice)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtPId.DataBindings.Add("Text", PId, "Value");
    txtPName.DataBindings.Add("Text", PName, "Value");
    txtPPrice.DataBindings.Add("Text", PPrice, "Value");
}
```

Comment: can u explain more

Comment: Your product edit form is completely disconnected from your datagridview as all you're doing is passing a copy of the string contents of each cell into the form. Therefore, once you've finished doing your edit, you need to write the edited values back to the datagrid. To do this you need a reference to where the data needs to go, hence my suggestion to add the DataGridViewCells into your constructor.